# Grunt+AngularJS SPA: Large JS blobs and CSS issues

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am creating a Single Page Application using AngularJS. I am using Yeoman, Grunt and Bower to manage the project. I have only recently started using these tools so please bear with me.

**Problem 1: Grunt creates a single large JS blob increasing the page load time.**

Yes, it minifies the JS files but there are **many** JS files. No single view requires all the files. But since there is only one minfied JS file, I am forced to load the entire JS blob even if the particular view requires only a subset of the blob.

The following solutions could help, how do I implement them in Grunt?:

1. Minifiy each file separately and link the required files in the view
   code: This is simple but not the most efficient technique as the browser would have to make one GET request per file.
2. Combine and minify all JS files required for a particular view.
3. Combine and minify all JS files required for a particular view except those files which are common to all views. Combine and minify common files separately.

Option 3 is my preferred choice but if it's not possible then I'll settle for 2 or even 1.

However I don't know how to configure Grunt to do this - i.e combine, minify & rename the JS files and then refactor the HTML where those JS file names where referenced.

**Problem 2: Cannot create view specific minifed CSS**

At present, Grunt creates a combined & minified CSS. The problem is, I do not wan't view specific CSS to be combined with the main CSS which is common for all views.

The whole point of having view specific CSS is to override some properties of the main CSS in some views.

I am not looking for a ready to use solution but some pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: I think this comes down to a lot of personal/team preference and workflow efficiencies. The thing is, that one massive file should be cached, so every subsequent visit by the same user does not require _any_ JS to download (meaning a one-time load delay). Of course, the other strategies you suggested are also possible, which is why I don't think this question really is "answerable" other than preference, opinion, and conjecture. Sorry, I know it's not what you would want in a response.

Comment: I don't know why you think it's a question of opinion. I am not not asking people to comment on pros and cons of a large application wide JS file vs smaller JS files for each view. I have already made up my mind about it - I want minimum possible JS size per view. I guess you thought what you thought beacuse I said "3 is the best option IMO". Just to be clear I am not asking "should I do X Y or Z" I am just saying "I would like to do Z but if that's not possible I'll be okay with Y or even X but as of not I'm unable to figure out how to do any of them with Grunt".

Comment: I see, well yes, I did make that assumption. In that case, I might recommend rewording the question a bit to clarify the specific programmatic issue you are having and what you have tried so far. I only day this because it help the chances of someone answering your question add you need. I'll take a look later, but I'm not at my desk for the rest of the day.